# I have integertaed and dedicated GPUs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, wine, cuda

I have no experience in the field of GPUs but I all I know since I installed the latest driver from Nvidia and it became my main GPU instead of intel, the moving windows is stuttering while is faster than intel's 
I don't know what CUDA means but I want the desktop to use intel and the games (wine) to use Nvidia , Just like windows. 
My question can also by read like how to properly configure a laptop with 2 gpus to work with linux and handle the hardware acceleration for videos

Comment: freshuser@ramy-Satellite-C50-A073:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
 Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: Please edit your question above and put additional information in the quotation.